# Name of this property: if $x * x = y * y \implies x = y$

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, binary-operations

Algebraically speaking, what's the name of this property?:

$x * x = y * y \implies x = y$

$*$ being a binary operation

Comment: Unique square roots?

Comment: My only query with this is that $x*x$ is not necessarily a "squaring".

Comment: I think "squaring" here is in an abstract sense, not the usual one. It can be division by two if the operation is usual addition over some numerical set. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I would simply say that the operation "$*$" admits *uniqueness of square roots*.

Just to be clear, following up the comment of Marc van Leeuwen (thanks!), if an element admits a square root, this is unique.

Comment: It doesn't actually say that the operation admits (arbitrary) square roots. However if you say the property claims "uniqueness of square roots", this does not imply it is claiming existence;

Comment: That's what I meant, @MarcvanLeeuwen, but I will edit for clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not a full answer...

Define the function $f(x)= x * x$

Then your property is equivalent to $f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$

I think that this means that $f(x)$ must be a one-to-one function.

Anyone care to extend / argue?

Comment: True! Further, all [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_%28algebra%29#Classification_by_properties) magmas satisfy such property but the opposite does not hold. For finite magmas, the given property corresponds to a generic bijection of the set on the diagonal of the Cayley table, while idempotence corresponds precisely to the identity function over the set on the diagonal.

Answer (score 3):

The operation defines an injective squaring operation.